# How to use Red Gate Ants Profiler on the Command Line

Tags: windows, command-line, memory-leaks, redgate, red-gate-ants

I am trying to use Redgate Ants memory profiler with the command line. I have seen the redgate page on the command line but did not find it very informative. Does anyone have a more detailed description on how to do this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no command line in ANTS Memory Profiler v4.3 or later. The ability to take a snapshot from within your code will however be re-introduced in v.7 due out mid January (See http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewforum.php?f=134 for access to beta builds as part of the early-access program).